# how can model: class1 or class2 have relation with class3 but both Simultaneous don't have relation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I have three classes:

Class 1 has One To Many relation with Class 3;

Class 2 has One To Many relation with Class 3:

Class 1 and 2 are not related.

How can model this database?

[image: busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Set the `ForeignKey` field to null if not needed. May validate that in `clean()` method.

```
class A(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class C(models.Model):
    # ...
    fkA = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True) # to null if not needed
    fkB = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True) # to null if not needed
    # ...


    def clean(self):
        # only one fk allowed
        if self.fkA and self.fkB:
            raise ValidationError("Relation either to A or to B - not both!")
        # one fk required
        if not self.fkA and not self.fkB:
            raise ValidationError("Relation to A or to B required!")
```

## Option 2

Work with model inheritance

```
class A(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class AbstractC(models.Model):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        # ...
        abstract = True

class CtoA(AbstractC)
    # ...
    fkA = models.ForeignKey(A)
    # ...

class CtoB(AbstractC)
    # ...
    fkB = models.ForeignKey(B)
    # ...
```

## Database migration:

`$ python manage.py makemigrations`

`$ python manage.py migrate`